# IP addresses of various daemons in Hadoop pseudo distributed mode

Tags: java, hadoop

I have installed Hadoop 2.7.1 in pseudo distributed mode. What are the IPs of following daemons:

```
IP address of Namenode?

IP address of Datanode?

IP address of Resource Manager?

IP address of Node Manager?
```

Contents of `/etc/hosts` file in my machine are as follows:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost

127.0.1.1   linuxPC
```

linuxPC is name of my machine.

Answer (score 1):

For Pseudo Distributed, use `localhost` for all daemons. `127.0.0.1` is the standard IP used for `localhost`.

If the cluster needs to be accessed from outside of the host, use the actual IP address of the host.

Answer (score 0):

You can access NN, SNN, etc using loopback address (`127.0.0.1 or localhost`) along with respected port numbers or you can use your actual IP `192.168.x.x` to view the respected WebUI's

If you have configured your `/etc/hosts` like below you can access WebUI with `hostname`

```
192.168.x.x   linuxpc
```